# Amazon S3 components for Delphi 2010

Tags: delphi, components, amazon-s3, delphi-2010

Besides the Amazon Integrator from /n software, are there any other Amazon S3 components available that can be used with Delphi 2010? I would use the one from /n software, but it has some issues (e.g. GetObjectInfo doesn't work if the object is stored in a specific location) and limitations (e.g. copying objects doesn't let you define replacement meta-data).

I don't have the time or resources to create such a component myself.

Thanks!

Comment: /n software fixed the GetObjectInfo bug, and hopefully they'll help with copying objects. Their support is very quick and helpful, so that's a good sign. It looks like I'll use them after all.

Comment: This may be a silly question, but does /n software provide you with sources for the components?  Maybe a source mod would be the quickest path to getting something with the functionality you want.

Comment: Justin: The actual code is in a DLL and no source is provided for that (the Delphi code is just a wrapper for calling the DLL). However, /n have so far fixed all the bugs and limitations I've reported to them so I've decided to use their component.

Answer (score 1):

Eldos has a [set of components](http://www.eldos.com/sbb/desc-cloud.php) for provider-independant cloud storage as part of their SecureBlackBox suit.

I haven't used it yet, but I've been using SBB for years and I've always been satisfied both with the product and the provided support.

Answer (score 0):

A quick search on google using "amazon s3 delphi" revealed: http://www.itwriting.com/s3.php

Comment: Thanks, but I've looked at this before. Unfortunately it's more of a bare-bones example to build on and not a complete solution.